# C#: ArgumentException - XYZ.DLL does not contain any UserControl types

Tags: c#, .net, exception, visual-studio-2005

I have moved my development PC to another location, and without any changes to the source I now get the above exception.  What could the be problem?

I am using C# in VS2005.

Comment: Do you mean you've physically moved your PC from one location to another, without changing anything at all on your PC's disk, or do you mean that you've changed which PC you're using?

Comment: @Martin: I have physically moved my PC. Nothing else. I should add that my internet access is now via a wireless router and before it was wired, but the behaviour still occurs when I disable the wireless device.

Comment: Hmmm. Something else must have happened around the same time. Even if it wasn't obvious at the time. I move my laptop around every day, from wired to wireless, from domain to non-domain, to airplane to (you get the idea - I move it quite a bit). Stuff like this doesn't just happen, but subtle things (like running Clean Build instead of Rebuild without noticing) can.

Answer (score 1):

A little bit late, but since this was the first question in search and there is no response.

In my case the library project contained line:

```
<Service Include="{94E38DFF-614B-4cbd-B67C-F211BB35CE8B}" />
```

In `<ItemGroup>`. This line need to be removed. (That was the first problem.) I suppose this line is used as some sort of debugging for Windows forms library and there was no valid control to be tested.

After removing this line, the real problem was found. I tried to start a library. That was the second problem. Therefore all that was needed was to change the start-up project from library to any executable.

When you moved the package from one PC to another, then the star-up project was changed.

Answer (score 0):

try to refresh reference to your **xyz.DLL** in Visual Studio, or remove it and add to reference.

Comment: What do you mean by "refresh reference"?

Comment: Where is physically located xyz.DLL?

Comment: In the Debug folder of the project.

Comment: http://screencast.com/t/ODg5NWMzY2 your xyz.dll must be referenced. In this images you can view how to add reference http://bloggingabout.net/cfs-filesystemfile.ashx/__key/CommunityServer.Blogs.Components.WeblogFiles/dennis.metablogapi/8737.AddReference1_5F00_6E58BE92.png and http://bloggingabout.net/cfs-filesystemfile.ashx/__key/CommunityServer.Blogs.Components.WeblogFiles/dennis.metablogapi/0243.AddReference2_5F00_4E3DB1D5.png

Comment: But why would it only happen after I move the PC?

Comment: I can't answer to this question, but may be you've created certificate file, and it's depends on your network configuration. but I agree with you, situation is very interesting.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the project was a DLL that should be loaded by another software, so if I try to run/debug that DLL project directly I get that error. I fixed by configuring VS Studio to open the another software (that loads the DLL in question). You can configure that by going to the "Project -> DEBUG -> Start External Program".